# Get shop with userId in Panel (Dashboard) react component if exists from asp.net webapi

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, axios, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I want to Get Shop Details For a logged in user in react component called `Panel`

If the shop exists for that user, it should show the details, otherwise should show a message.

Here is the Panel react component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import axios from "axios";
import config from 'config';
const url = `${config.apiUrl}/api/Shops`
    export const Panel=()=> {
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
        const[shop,setShop]=useState(undefined);
          
          const user=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
           
          useEffect(()=>{
          axios.get(url + `userId=${user.id}`).then((res)=>{
            setShop(res.data);
           } );
          setTimeout(()=>{
            setLoading(false);
          },1000)
       
          },[]);

          console.log("shop",shop);
          //
          return (     
            <div>
          {loading === true ? (<CircularProgress />): (
     
      <div>
         <h2> Dashboard</h2>
         
        {shop[0]!=undefined ? <h3>{shop[0].storeName}</h3>:<h3>No Details Found</h3>}
        
     </div>
      )
      }
      </div>
      );
    }
```

Here is the `Shop` model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class Shop
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(150)]
        public string StoreName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
       public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is controller - get shop by Id:

```
    // GET: api/Shops/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Shop>> GetShop(int id)
    {
        var shop = await _context.Shops.FindAsync(id);

        if (shop == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return shop;
    }
```

Here is Get Shop By userId:

```
    // GET: api/Shops/5
    [HttpGet("{userId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Shop>> Panel(int userId)
    {
        var shop = await _context.Shops.FindAsync(userId);

        if (shop == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return shop;
    }
```

The problem is that I want to Get the Shop By userId instead of id, because we have only `userId` based on which we could get shop. We don't have shop `id`.

Moreover, if there is problem in my axios call ,than also help to workaround.

Thanks in advance.

My app uses react+ node with front end and asp.net web api as backend.

Comment: Hi @Fiaz Ahmed Ranjha, so your problem is do not know how to get the shop by userId? And did you debug the code and check if the userId correctly passed to backend?

Comment: Hi @Fiaz Ahmed Ranjha, any update?

Comment: Hi @Rena ,your given changes are right  and i changed the code line.now it feches all the shops instead of single shop.i think the requests does not go into Panel function of controller or there is any other  problem,which i could not find uptill now.

Comment: Hi @Fiaz Ahmed Ranjha, I have to say my code even your code are used to find single shop. It is impossible to find all the shops. I suggest you can set breakpoint to check if you hit the wrong action.

Comment: Hi @Rena ,thank you for help. as you suggested I checked and changed  `[HttpGet("{userId}")]` to `[HttpGet("panel")]` and line of code to ` axios.get(url + `/panel?userId=${user.id}`).then((res)=>{ ` and worked as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the shop data by userId, modify your code like below:

```
var shop = await _context.Shops.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a=>a.UserId==userId);
```